# Writing dicitonary to JSON using Python

Tags: python, json

I'm new to Python programming, so do bear with me if I make any mistakes anywhere

I'm trying to write a json file using 2 dictionaries and dump the output to the file using the following code on Windows

```
import json
import sys
import string
from time import strftime

scan_results = open("scan_results.txt", "r")
saved = sys.stdout
f = file('report.json', 'wb')
sys.stdout = f
for line in scan_results:
    if ".jpg" in line:
        lst = []
        result = line.split('\\')
        result_split = result[5].split(' ')
        filename = result_split[0]
        raw_status = result_split[3]
        if "OK" in raw_status:
            status = "Okay"
            status_code = "0"
        dict = {'FileName': filename, 'DateTime': strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), 'statusCode': status_code, 'Description': status}
        dict2 = {filename : dict}
        print json.dumps(dict2)
sys.stdout = saved
f.close()
print "JSON report written"
```

The problem is, the output that I have is

```
{
    "car-30537.jpg": {
        "statusCode": "0",
        "DateTime": "2012-02-07 09:52:26",
        "Description": "Okay",
        "FileName": "car-30537.jpg"
    }
}{
    "car-30538.jpg": {
        "statusCode": "0",
        "DateTime": "2012-02-07 09:52:26",
        "Description": "Okay",
        "FileName": "car-30538.jpg"
    }
}
```

whereas the output that I want is

```
{
    "car-30537.jpg": {
        "statusCode": "0",
        "DateTime": "2012-02-07 09:52:26",
        "Description": "Okay",
        "FileName": "car-30537.jpg"
    },
    {
    "car-30538.jpg": {
        "statusCode": "0",
        "DateTime": "2012-02-07 09:52:26",
        "Description": "Okay",
        "FileName": "car-30538.jpg"
    }
}
```

Is there any ways to correct this problem? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are making lots of dicts, while you only need one main containing one:

```
import json
import sys
import string
from time import strftime

scan_results = open("scan_results.txt", "r")
saved = sys.stdout
f = file('report.json', 'wb')
sys.stdout = f
dict2 = {} #Create one output dict
for line in scan_results:
    if ".jpg" in line:
        lst = []
        result = line.split('\\')
        result_split = result[5].split(' ')
        filename = result_split[0]
        raw_status = result_split[3]
        if "OK" in raw_status:
            status = "Okay"
            status_code = "0"
        dict2[filename] = {'FileName': filename, 'DateTime': strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S"), 'statusCode': status_code, 'Description': status} #Add to that dict.
print json.dumps(dict2) #Print it out at the end.
sys.stdout = saved
f.close()
print "JSON report written"
```

I added comments to modified lines.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the quick reply. It is still giving me the first output as mentioned in my question

Comment: @androidnoob Are you sure? That doesn't seem right. Could you give me your data file (just add it to your question) so I can test it?

Comment: Opps, I placed the `print json.dumps(dict2)` at the wrong indent after double checking. Thanks a lot for your help!

Comment: This code is pretty crazy. (1) `lst` is written to but never read (2) status is always Okay, status_code is always 0 (3) No good reason to modify sys.stdout (4) Code should open for read then create dict then open for write. This intermixes all three. (5) string import is not used (6) file is opened with two idioms -- file() and open().... As far as I can tell, this would do the same thing and be substantially cleaner: http://pastebin.com/97PM1jsb

Comment: @hughdbrown Completely agree on that front - I only made the changes needed to make it work as asked, I didn't make any other changes.

Comment: @hughdbrown I have omitted some parts of the code because it is confidential so a few lines may seem crazy.